# Report Viewer Control Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am trying to create link SQL Server 2005 Report Server Reports in VS 2010 and I get an error "Remote Report Processing requires Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services or later". How do i downgrade the control to the one from 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way I know how to get around this is to use an older version of Visual Studio for this type of development. Not much of a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the 2005 version of the report viewer control. Unfortunately MS doesn't allow this to be used in 2010. There's probably a better technology-related reason than "Make you upgrade to 2008", but that's how I feel about this.

**However**, You have some hoops to jump through:

- The old control must be put on a *WinForms* form **with VS 2008** (or 2005).
- The new application must be using **the full .Net 4.0 profile**.
- If your main application is signed, the DLL you create in VS 2008 **must have a strong name key**.
- The form in VS 2010, containing the control you built in VS 2008, will not open in design view in VS 2010.
- If you're using WPF, there is no native control - you must resort to Windows Forms Interop to make this happen, hosting the WinForms control.

Also keep in mind that there are several versions of the Report Viewer control out there:
 - v8.0 = VS 2005, VS 2008, SQL 2005
 - v9.0 = VS 2008, SQL 2008
 - v9.X = VS 2008, VS 2010, SQL 2008 R2
 - v10  = VS 2010, SQL 2008 R2

Hope this helps you.